# How to add Textbox using Python Snack TUI

Tags: python

How to add a Textbox element using the **Python-Newt** [Snack library](http://www.wanware.com/tsgdocs/snack.html)    and the Class definition found [here](http://pydoc.org/1.5.2/snack.html#Textbox)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os, sys
from snack import *

screen = SnackScreen()
g = Grid(2, 2)
g.setField(Textbox(40, 1, "Enter:") , 0, 0)
screen.gridWrappedWindow(g, "Title")
f = Form()
f.add(g)
f.run()
screen.popWindow()
screen.finish()
```

It runs but only shows "Enter: " and I am unable to input any text since I don't see an input field.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `text` parameter to a `Textbox` is the initial text for the input field, not a separate label for it. So, you're supposed to edit that "Enter: ", not type something somewhere else. (That being said, I haven't used snack in _forever_, since… whenever Mandrake Linux had a fork of one of Red Hat's config utils?)

Comment: its displayed as a Label and I can't input any text. I have tried setting the "text" to "" and see nothing displayed.

Comment: I only had success with `EntryWindow(screen, 'Title', 'Enter the following requirements',['Enter Name:'])` but this function only accepts text fields not other widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Textbox, I replaced it with Entry widget.